Passport JS and express-session: req.isAuthenticated() false in production , returns true in development
I am responding to request from client for protected resources based on whether the req.isAuthenticated() flag returns true or false
I am hosting my app on render
When i had completed the initial phases of the project on dev environment i decided to check if things were working fine , only to find it wasnt
Upon successfull login i am redirecting user to a home page and making an api call inside of useEffect to an endpoint called /getUserDetails , here i only send the resources if the req.isAuthenticated() returns true , this is happening in dev but not happening in production
I tried changing the order of middlewares , setting secure flag inside cookie inside express session to true
Relevant part of the code ---
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import session from "express-session";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from "passport-google-oauth20";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";
import { profileRouter } from "./routes/profileRouter.js";
//import "./utils/passport.js"
import { User } from "./models/User.js";
dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

//DATABASE CONNECTION
const DB = process.env.DB_STRING.replace("<password>", process.env.DB_PASSWORD);
mongoose
  .connect(DB)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DATABASE CONNECTION WAS SUCCESSFULL!");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(`${error} --- error connecting to DATABASE `);
  });

app.use(
  cors({
    origin:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? process.env.CLIENT_URL_DEV
        : process.env.CLIENT_URL_PROD,
    credentials: true,
    methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    resave: false, //changes req,session.cookie when session object is modified
    saveUninitialized: false, //only stores session to session store if modified
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: DB,
      collectionName: "sessions",
    }),
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? false : true
    },
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: `${
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
          ? process.env.API_URL_DEV + "/auth/google/callback"
          : process.env.API_URL_PROD + "/auth/google/callback"
      }`,
    },

    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      console.log(profile, " profile info \n");
      const userExists = await User.findOne({
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        name: profile.displayName
      })

      if (!userExists) {

        await User.create({
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          name: profile.displayName,
          profilePhoto: profile.photos[0].value
        });


      }

      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});



app.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: ["email", "profile"],
  }),
  async (req, res) => {
    console.log(`/auth/google/callback hit with a req --- ${JSON.stringify(req.user)} \n`)
    if (!req.user) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: "Authentication failed" });
    } else {
     
      res.redirect(
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
          ? process.env.CLIENT_URL_DEV 
          : process.env.CLIENT_URL_PROD
      );
    }
    // return user details
  }
);

app.use("/profile", profileRouter)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("get req received to / endpoint \n");
  res.send("<h1>Hello</h1>");
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6007;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server listening on port ${PORT} \n`);
});


can please elaborate exactly error is logging ? Have you checked env file of prod. ?

@Jack --- in the getUserDetails endpoint req.isAuthenticated() is false

It is likely because the connection you are using isn't encrypted, and the secure cookies can only be sent over HTTPS. Try setting secure to just to false to confirm.
Have a look at this post on setting up Nginx as a reverse proxy in docker (not 100% certain what you are using on the front end, but this looks like a Mongo-Express-React-Node app) to deal with HTTPS certificates:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63226398/22857893
The guide from the above post:
https://pentacent.medium.com/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71
Also, double-check your production environment variable and ensure there are no typos like http versus https.

based on whether the dev environment is production or development i am setting the secure flag to true in the case of latter and false in the case of former

Also i am using render to deploy
